# ROR + TodayDate in UTC Format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

If I have `@today = Date.today.to_s`, how do I convert `@today into UTC` (with the appropriate date only)?
Here I need is only date for example 2011-03-08 ie 08 March 2011. Please suggest something ?

Acutally I am looking for Yesterday date ??

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for, but take a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html and see what question you still have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to convert it to a `Time` object (or just use Time anyway) and then call `Time#utc`:

```
irb > Time.now
 => Tue Mar 08 15:32:36 +1100 2011 
irb > Time.now.utc
 => Tue Mar 08 04:32:40 UTC 2011
```

You can then format it however you need it:

```
irb > @today = Time.now.utc
 => Tue Mar 08 04:34:25 UTC 2011 
irb > @today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
 => "2011-03-08"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert @today into UTC.
Then try this

```
>> @today = Date.today.to_s
>> DateTime.parse(@today)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
1.day.ago.utc
```

or

```
1.day.ago.utc.strftime('%b %B, %Y')
```

The format below should give you the date format of Yesterday which you are looking for formatted as 07 March, 2011. Look into the ruby Time class manual for more information on **strftime** time formating function. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I strongly recommend you to move towards time zones in rails. Its easier and lot more convenient to work with than Time.now. You should be able to set the time zone in environment.rb with `config.time_zone = "Chennai"` or your time zone. After doing this, you should be able to get the time with UTC information by Doing `Time.zone.now`. To find the UTC offset, you could type `Time.zone`.