# ROR + TodayDate in Different Format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have @today = Date.today.to_s, how do I convert @today into UTC (with the appropriate date only)? But the format should be like this : 2011-03-08 00:00:00

Acutally I am looking for Yesterday date also ??

Comment: I found this function also work same as Date.yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')

Comment: possible duplicate of [ROR + TodayDate in UTC Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228337/ror-todaydate-in-utc-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me to get yesterday at time 00hr

```
Date.yesterday.to_time.utc.at_beginning_of_day
=> Sun Mar 06 00:00:00 UTC 2011
```

Comment: Can use Date.yesterday.to_time.utc.at_beginning_of_day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for the format specified

Comment: Thanx Buddy, Infact I found this function also work same as Date.yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')

Comment: yes..but at_beginning_of_day is the method you use to get the start time but of course we can use strftime to convert to any format. You can refer http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/DateTime/Calculations.html for DateTime calculations

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its the correct way to do it but it works

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Date.today.to_time.utc
 => 2011-03-07 18:15:00 UTC
```

and for yesterday, you can subtract a day form today

```
(Date.today-1.day).to_time.utc
 => 2011-03-06 18:15:00 UTC
```

Comment: Buddy, I need the value as 2011-03-07 00:00:00, use any type of variable. above it's a prototype...

Answer (score 0):

For Yesterday Date.

> > @date = Date.yesterday
> >     => Mon, 07 Mar 2011
> >
> > @date.to_time.utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
> >     => "2011-03-06 18:30:00"

Comment: Format is specified by me ... plz see above

Answer (score 0):

This will do(`%F - %Y-%m-%d` and `%T - %H:%M:%S`)

```
Date.today.strftime("%F %T")
Date.yesterday.strftime("%F %T")
```

If you are particular about UTC time, you should do like this

```
(Time.now.utc).to_date.strftime("%F %T")
(Time.now.utc - 1.day).to_date.strftime("%F %T")
```